# Error: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to drag and drop an image on a div. The image does not get get dragged onto the div and gives the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.draganddrop.html:20 dropdraganddrop.html:26 ondrop
```

Code

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
     <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Creativity Dashboard</title>

        <!-- Required CSS -->
        <link href="css/movingboxes.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/compare.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
           <link href="css/movingboxes-ie.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Required script -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.movingboxes.js"></script>

        <!-- Demo only -->
        <link href="demo/demo.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="demo/demo.js"></script>

        <script>
           function allowDrop(ev) {
              ev.preventDefault();
           }

           function drag(ev) {
              ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
           }

           function drop(ev) {
              ev.preventDefault();
              var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
              ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
           }
        </script>
        <style>
           /* Overall & panel width defined using css in MovingBoxes version 2.2.2+ */
           #slider-one {
              width: 1003px;
           }

           #slider-one>li {
              width: 150px;
           }
        </style>
     </head>

     <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
           <!-- Slider #1 -->
           <ul id="slider-one">

              <li><img id="drag1" src="demo/1.jpg" draggable="true"
                 ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="picture"></li>

              <li><img id="drag2" src="demo/2.jpg" draggable="true"
                 ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="picture"></li>

              <li><img id="drag3" src="demo/3.jpg" draggable="true"
                 ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="picture"></li>

              <li><img id="drag5" src="demo/4.jpg" draggable="true"
                 ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="picture"></li>

              <li><img id="drag6" src="demo/5.jpg" draggable="true"
                 ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="picture"></li>

              <li><img id="drag7" src="demo/6.jpg" draggable="true"
                 ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="picture" id="astronaut"></li>

              <li><img id="drag8" src="demo/7.jpg" draggable="true"
                 ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="picture"></li>

           </ul>
           <!-- end Slider #1 -->
           <div id="dragAnddrop" ondrop="drop(event)"
              ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="width: 12em; height: 12em">
           </div>
        </div>

        <div>
           <div class="left">
              <img id="drag" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"
                 src="images/startingImage.jpg" style="width: 12em;" alt="picture">

           </div>
           <div class="middle ">
              <img id="image3" src="images/startingImage.jpg" class="image-size"
                 alt="picture" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"> <img
                 src="images/harvest.jpg" class="image-size" alt="picture">
           </div>
           <div class="right">
              <img src="images/startingImage.jpg" style="width: 12em;"
                 alt="picture">
           </div>
        </div>
     </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById` is likely returning null, check the value of `data`

Comment: You use `ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));` but if there is no element with id `data` then `document.getElementById` will return `null`. So `ev.target.appendChild(null)` will throw.

Comment: It says Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functioncompare.html:92 ondragstart

Comment: For those who were searching for an exact answer in one go: [Appending HTML using native JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42517697/appending-html-using-native-javascript)

Answer (score 351):

It's actually a simple answer.

Your function is returning a string rather than the `div` node. `appendChild` can only append a node.

For example, if you try to appendChild the string:

```
var z = '<p>test satu dua tiga</p>'; // is a string 
document.body.appendChild(z);
```

The above code will never work. What will work is:

```
var z = document.createElement('p'); // is a node
z.innerHTML = 'test satu dua tiga';
document.body.appendChild(z);
```

Comment: @nmnsud, it is included above and in practically every project nowadays.

Comment: Bad question but do we have to remove the newly created element after appending? I am asking this as in some situations where there will be a loop and inside loo there will be append child options. Will there be any memory issue or more garbage elements created in dom ?

Comment: In this case you will get a extra <p> tag.

Answer (score 19):

This can happen if you accidentally are not dragging the element that does have an id assigned (for example you are dragging the surrounding element). In that case the ID is empty and the function drag() is assigning an empty value which is then passed to drop() and fails there.

Try assigning the ids to all of your elements, including the tds, divs, or whatever is around your draggable element.

Answer (score 16):

You may also use `element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', data);`

Please read the "Security considerations" on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

Answer (score 11):

In my case, there was no string on which i was calling `appendChild`, the object i was passing on `appendChild` argument was wrong, it was an array and i had pass an element object, so i used `divel.appendChild(childel[0])` instead of `divel.appendChild(childel)` and it worked. Hope it help someone.

Answer (score 0):

use `ondragstart(event)` instead of `ondrag(event)`

Answer (score 0):

For future readers who want to use React 17 new react/jsx-transform to just use jsx syntax without using any hook:

1. uninstall react via `npm uninstall react`
2. keep your `react-dom`
3. update babel config. Add:

   ```js
   plugins: [
     ['@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx', { runtime: 'automatic' }],
   ]
   ```

   note: you can replace `@babel/preset-react` with `@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx`, as indicated in this code.
4. change your syntax to

   ```js
   ReactDOM.render(<Comp/>, document.getElementById('fuc_'))
   ```