# How to iterate each character of a string in .innerHTML (for-loop)?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, innerhtml

Hi let's assume that I have the following code:

```
var information_paragraph = document.getElementById(myDivElement);
var infoText = "Hello World!";
information_paragraph.innerHTML = infoText;
```

So instead of adding the whole string "Hello World!", I was thinking if I can add a char of that string one at a time. How to access the characters of the string and create a for loop to add content in the innerHTML rather than replacing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I process each letter of text using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966476/how-can-i-process-each-letter-of-text-using-javascript) and [Appending using native javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42517697/appending-html-using-native-javascript)

Comment: `for(var char of text)`?

Answer (score 4):

Convert string to array and iterate?

```js
document.getElementById('block').innerHTML.split('').forEach(function(i){
  console.log(i);
});
```

```html
<div id="block">Text</div>
```

Comment: @nickzoum there's a plenty of variants to do this, it's one of them

Comment: You don't seem to have fully answered the question: *How to access the characters of the string and create a for loop to add content in the innerHTML rather than replacing it*

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to use the string as array and append it to the inner html
if you ant it all in a sane line remove `"</br>"+`

```js
var information_paragraph = document.getElementById("myDivElement");
var infoText = "Hello World!";
for(i = 0; i < infoText.length; i++)
information_paragraph.innerHTML += "<br/>"+infoText[i];
```

```html
<div id="myDivElement">
</div>
```

Comment: `</br>` is not a valid tag - if you were to self close it, you need to put the slash on the other side `<br/>` but html 5 doesn't need the slash at all

Comment: @Pete Correct its a typo I will change it . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think may this work

```
const  information_paragraph = 
document.getElementById('myDivElement');
let  infoText = "Hello World!"; 
let infoTextLetters ;
for(i in infoText){
  infoTextLetters +=  `
   <br> ${infoText[i]} ` ;

information_paragraph.innerHTML = infoTextLetters
```