# To do list using JavaScript problems

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to make a "To do list" using JavaScript and it doesn't work.I tried different things but it won't work.Please help. Thanks!

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
    var li = "<li>" + text + "</li>";
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
   }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text"><br><br>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Write">
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.draganddrop.html:20 dropdraganddrop.html:26 ondrop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079598/uncaught-typeerror-failed-to-execute-appendchild-on-node-parameter-1-is-no)

Answer (score 2):

Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the console.

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
>       at HTMLInputElement.document.getElementById.onclick

You are passing a string to `appendChild`, but the value it expects is an **node** such as an **element**.

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
  var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text"><br><br>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Write">
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: your code works here on this "Run code snippet" thing, but when I copy&paste it into a Notepad++ it doesn't work. help?

Comment: I can't see what you are doing wrong. Does the console complain about trying to access onclick of null? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using **innerHTML** as well, as shown below :

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
  var text = document.getElementById("text").value;     
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML+="<li>"+text+"</li>";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text"><br><br>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Write">
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Like `Quentin` said but you don't need to create node, you can directly append string with function [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
    var li = "<li>" + text + "</li>";
    document.getElementById("list").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", li);
   }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text"><br><br>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Write">
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="text" id="text"><input type="button" id="button" value="Write">
```

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
            var node = document.createElement("li");                
            var textnode = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("text").value);    
            node.appendChild(textnode);                             
            document.getElementById("list").appendChild(node);
        }
```

you can do this way

Comment: Could u tell me ? What is wrong ? I tried it and it has worked.