# Trying to insert an HTML Element into an another HTML Element using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, format, output

> Hello everybody, so iam Trying to insert an HTML Element into an another HTML Element using Javascript.

I Tried using `.insertAdjacentHTML` but it inserts it near to the target element as the positions isn't suitable for me... and `.html` inserts it as text format not HTML format

here is what i tried coding:-

```
   SendClientMessage(COLORS_.white, "15px", "none", '<div class="ls-files">' + CMDS_List + '</div>');
   function SendClientMessage(color, font, align = 'none', message)
   {
      if(align !== "none")
      {
         output_.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p style="color: ' + color + '; font-size: ' + font + '; text-align: ' + align + ';">' + message + '</p>'); 
      }
      else if(align === "none")
      {
         output_.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p style="color: ' + color + '; font-size: ' + font + ';">' + message + '</p>'); 
      }
   }
```

the output:-

```
<p style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 15px;"></p>
<div class="ls-files">clear,clock,dati,ping,uname,whoami,cmd,</div>
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: `<p style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 15px;"><div class="ls-files">clear,clock,dati,ping,uname,whoami,cmd,</div></p>`

Comment: did u tried innerHTML or appendChild?

Comment: `.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", ...)` acts, more or less, like `.appendChild()`. The output shown is therefore only possible if `output_` is not the `p` tag.

Comment: @brk on trying to use appendChild i have got an error `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.` so i searched for any smilliar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079598/uncaught-typeerror-failed-to-execute-appendchild-on-node-parameter-1-is-no but i couldn't insert any stylesheets with this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only put inline elements like *span* or *a* into a *p* tag using insertAdjacentHTML because it is using an html parser that checks for properly formatted html before inserting the content.

```js
let CMDS_List = 'clear,clock,dati,ping,uname,whoami,cmd,';

SendClientMessage('white', "15px", "none", '<span class="ls-files">' + CMDS_List + '</span>');

function SendClientMessage(color, font, align = 'none', message) {
  let output_ = document.getElementById('output');
  if (align !== "none") {
    output_.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p style="color: ' + color + '; font-size: ' + font + '; text-align: ' + align + ';">' + message + '</p>');
  } else if (align === "none") {
    output_.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p style="color: ' + color + '; font-size: ' + font + ';">' + message + '</p>');
  }
}
```

```css
  body {
  background: #999;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```