# How to Add border to a table using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add border to my table using javascript so when I am using

```
var table=document.createElement("table").style.border="1px solid";
```

and try to append the row to this table like this

```
 table.appendChild(newRow);
```

above line is throwing exception as follows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

and if I try to execute the same code without giving border it executes properly
please help me with this.

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53189556/edit), then click the snippet editor `[<>]` and create a [mcve]

Comment: if you `console.log(table)`, you'll see it's not a Node element, but a string. You need to separate your line into two.

Comment: Duplicate of many. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079598/uncaught-typeerror-failed-to-execute-appendchild-on-node-parameter-1-is-no

Comment: Please perform [a minimum of research](https://www.google.nl/search?q=Failed+to+execute+%27appendChild%27+on+%27Node%27+style+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning `"1px solid"` to the `border` property, and the result of evaluating that (also `"1px solid"`) to `table`.

It is a string, so it is quite natural that it doesn't have an `appendChild` method.

If you want to access the table itself later on, then you need to store *the table itself* in a variable.

```
var table = document.createElement("table");
table.style.border = "1px solid";
table.appendChild(newRow);
```

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=Failed+to+execute+%27appendChild%27+on+%27Node%27+style+site:stackoverflow.com