# Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. Ways to remove an element

Tags: javascript

I tried to delete an item in several ways. One works the rest do not, I do not understand why.

```
function AppendPF(){    
    var test = document.getElementById('h31').innerText;
    if (test === 'How it works.') text3 = text3en;
    if (test === 'Как это работает.') text3 = text3ru;
    var test2=document.getElementById('text3');
    if (!test2){
         var newDiv2= document.createElement('div');
         newDiv2.innerHTML = '<div id="text3">'+text3+'</div>';
         document.getElementById('text3app').appendChild(newDiv2.firstChild);
    } else if (test2){
        document.getElementById('text3app').removeChild(document.getElementById('text3app').childNodes[0]);//That work

        document.getElementById('text3app').removeChild('text3');//NOT WORKING
        document.getElementById('text3').parentNode.removeChild('text3');//NOT WORKING
        var pn=document.getElementById('text3').parentNode;//.removeChild('text3');
        pn.removeChild('text3');//NOT WORKING
    }    
}
```

While figuring out found ways to remove an item. Workers)

```
// These work can be so
document.getElementById('text3').remove();
document.getElementById("text3app").innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.draganddrop.html:20 dropdraganddrop.html:26 ondrop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079598/uncaught-typeerror-failed-to-execute-appendchild-on-node-parameter-1-is-no)

Comment: `removeChild` expects to be passed a DOM element, but you are passing it a string (`'text3'). Please [read the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Felix Kling. Right code:

```
document.getElementById('text3app').removeChild(document.getElementById('text3')); 
                document.getElementById('text3').parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById('text3'));
                var pn=document.getElementById('text3').parentNode;//.removeChild('text3');
                pn.removeChild(document.getElementById('text3'));
```