# Turning an array into a list using appendChild

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

How do I create a function accepts two parameters, the first is a list element that should be added to, the second is an array of strings that will be turned into list items.

The parameters were the element and the arr. I tried to create the list element and append the array strings into the element using appendChild.

```js
function filler(elem, arr){
  elem = document.createElement("li");
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    elem.appendChild(arr[i]);
  }
}
```

Error message:

> Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type
>   'Node'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079598/error-failed-to-execute-appendchild-on-node-parameter-1-is-not-of-type-no

Comment: Why are overwriting `elem`?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues:

1. You're reinitializing `elem` within your function, so, the `elem` passed through will be overwritten, meaning you won't be able to append elements to it.
2. You're trying to append a string to your `elem` element. This won't work as you need to append a node (as [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) accepts a node, not a string). To append a node, you can create a `<li>` HTML element in your JS by using [`document.createElement("li")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), which you can then set the text to be that of your current array value (using `.textContent`).

See example below:

```js
function filler(elem, arr){
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = arr[i];
    elem.appendChild(li);
  }
}

const lst = document.getElementById('lst');
filler(lst, ["eggs", "bread", "butter"]);
```

```html
<ul id="lst"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fill the elements and return the full list.

```
function filler(elem, arr){
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    listItem = document.createElement('li');
    listItem.innerHTML = arr[i];
    elem.appendChild(listItem);
  }
  return elem;
}
```

Here is a use case `filler(document.createElement('ul'), ['a', 'b', 'c']);`

Comment: better use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`

Comment: Depends on what OP wants actually, could be a list of valid HTML elements?