# Cant append parsed HTML with appendChild to a div

Tags: javascript, html, jinja2

Why cant I append pasted html with appendChild? This is my code:

```js
<div id="byeeee"></div>

var appenddescription = $.parseHTML("<h1>hello</h1> bye<br>");

document.getElementById("byeeee").appendChild(appenddescription);
```

My goal is to parse the html and append it to the div. When I try the code above I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

I tried to use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31800768/15677215 but it didnt help

P.S: I'm using Jinja as a templating engine. In my real code the JavaScript would look like

```js
var appenddescription = $.parseHTML("{{hello}}");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use jQuery, it's discouraged to mix it with JS. Use jQuery's `.append()` like so:

```js
var appenddescription = $.parseHTML("<h1>hello</h1> bye<br>");
$("#byeeee").append(appenddescription);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="byeeee"></div>
```

To turn off HTML escaping in Jinja, use:

```
var appenddescription = $.parseHTML("{{hello|safe}}");
```

[jQuery.parseHTML() | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/)

Comment: Hm, not sure why. But when I try this on my website it says ``<h1>hello</h1> bye<br>`` (literally) the <br>'s dont make a new line. If it helps, Im using the templating engine Jinja to generate whats in parseHTML() . Appending does work though

Comment: @mcdonalds291 That's odd... I'm not familiar with that templating engine but does it by any chance escape HTML tag start/ends?

Comment: I dont believe it does. I will post a screenshot of how it looks when using inspect element.

Comment: Here is that screenshot https://i.imgur.com/PVodJFw.png

Comment: @mcdonalds291 If dev tools show the literal string, then that's an indicator that the string is being escaped. Try double clicking the text, which should reveal whether the `<` characters are escaped.

Comment: How would I see if the ``<`` characters are escaped? I dont see any ``\``'s

Comment: @mcdonalds291 Right click the element and click 'Edit as HTML'. Does it look contain things like this? `&lt;tagname&gt;`

Comment: Yes! It does. When I edit as HTML it shows ``hello &lt;br&gt; &lt;br&gt; &lt;h1&gt;bye&lt;/h1&gt;``(This is why I thought parseHTML wasn't working)

Comment: @mcdonalds291 In that case, [turning off auto-escaping in Jinja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206344/passing-html-to-template-using-flask-jinja2) might be the way to go :)

Comment: @mcdonalds291 I've updated my answer for Jinja. It should work now

Comment: Yess! Thank you so much! It works flawlessly. To anyone who is reading this discussion, make sure you trust the input your injecting into your code before using | safe

Comment: @mcdonalds291 Glad to help :) Please consider accepting if it solves your question.